# executables with nvcc are larger than with gcc/g++ and OpenCL

Tags: c++, cuda, g++, opencl, nvcc

This is just something that I've noticed and was curious if there was a reason for it.

Compiling some standard helloworld code with Nvidia's nvcc compiler from it's cuda 7.0 toolkit on Ubuntu 14.04 results in an executable of the following size:

```
liang@liang-EX58-UD3R:~/Documents/cuda-test$ nvcc cudahello.cu -o cudahello
liang@liang-EX58-UD3R:~/Documents/cuda-test$ ls -lah cudahello
-rwxrwxr-x 1 liang liang 508K Jun 25 12:08 cudahello
```

The program is just a simple hello world program, with no kernel calls:

```
//cudahello.cu
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "helloworld\n";
    return 0;
}
```

On the otherhand, an OpenCL is more the expected size for a C++ executable:

```
liang@liang-EX58-UD3R:~/Documents/opencl-test$ g++ -Wall -std=c++11 oclhello.cpp -lOpenCL -o oclhello
liang@liang-EX58-UD3R:~/Documents/opencl-test$ ls -lah oclhello
-rwxrwxr-x 1 liang liang 8.9K Jun 25 12:08 oclhello
```

This is also a simple helloworld program:

```
//oclhello.cpp
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "helloworld";
    return 0;
}
```

Was there a reason for the CUDA executable being considerably larger?
I've found that even with OpenCL functions being used in a C/C++ program, the executable doesn't grow to the size of CUDA executables.

Comment: I don't know much about `nvcc`, but are you comparing executables with debug info? Try stripping the two executables (`strip cudahello oclhello`) and comparing their size. Also compare what libraries they are linking to (with `ldd`). It's possible `nvcc` is statically linking while `g++` is dynamically linking.

Comment: Hmm not too sure about strip, but I've actually done a diff between a gcc and an nvcc binary compiled from identical code, and found that the nvcc program has a lot in common with the gcc except for a large chunk of extra data in a blob somewhere in the executable.

Comment: It is important to remember nvcc isn't a compiler. It is a *compiler drvier* - it steers compilation, but that is all it does. In both cases, the same g++ compiler is used. All that nvcc can ever do is change compile and linker options (in this case the option is to statically link the CUDA runtime library)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary difference is that in your CUDA case, you are *statically* linking to libcudart, the cuda runtime library, which adds ~500K minimum to the executable size.

The openCL executable is *dynamically* linked to libOpenCL.so, which means the size of that library does not contribute to the size of the executable.

To achieve approximate parity, link your cuda application with the additional switch:

```
--cudart shared
```

which will [force dynamic linking to libcudart](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#nvcc-command-options), and the CUDA executable size will drop down a lot.

You can also observe the linking difference using `ldd`.

Comment: Seems to make logical sense, thanks rob!
`liang@liang-EX58-UD3R:~/Documents/cuda-test$ nvcc --cudart shared cudahello.cu -o cudahello
liang@liang-EX58-UD3R:~/Documents/cuda-test$ ls -lah cudahello
-rwxrwxr-x 1 liang liang 15K Jun 25 16:02 cudahello`